# ClickOnce Setup instantly stops executing

Tags: visual-studio-2012, vsto, clickonce, add-in, .net-4.5

I've got a problem with a ClickOnce Setup and have absolutely no idea what I'm doing wrong...

I'm trying to publish a VSTO AddIn for Outlook 2013 using VS2012. However when I click on the Setup.exe created by the ClickOnce Publish the Setup shows the small installation window for about half a second and then instantly disappears again. This without showing any error message or generating any event log entries at all.

- The ClickOnce manifest is signed with a test certificate (self-signed
  certificate).
- The assembly is not signed. (However if I choose to sign it, nothing changes)
- I'm publishing to the filesystem using CD or DVD-ROM as installation path (publishing to IIS results in the same problem)

Yesterday this had worked. Today it won't. Hadn't changed anything since then...

Has anyone an idea what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found the answer... After many tries to reproduce the problem i noticed the following:

If I create a new project don't change anything but create manually a test certificate the published setup won't run, but if I don't change anything at all it works...

As ClickOnce creates a Certificate for signing the manifest I started comparing the differences between those certificates. Comes out: the hash algorithm has to be sha1

This certificate doesn't work. And the installer will abort without giving an hint about what's wrong:

[image: SHA256 Certificate]

This certificate works.

[image: SHA1 Certificate]

One might think that the Setup would give at least a hint about what might be wrong instead of just aborting.

I hope if someone else stumbles upon this issue this might help :)

Comment: Can you double check your answer... the words "This" and "This" don't have any image associated with it.  Perhaps just re-word it to include more descriptive text about what "this" is.  Thanks.

Comment: .NET 4.5 version of the tool introduces a new -a/-Algorithm switch that allows you to choose between sha1RSA and sha256RSA:
`Manifest Generation and Editing Tool (Mage.exe, .NET Framework 4.5)`[link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acz3y3te%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)