# ClickOnce VSTO CommonLanguageRuntime

Tags: c#, vsto, clickonce, .net-4.8

I created an MS Word plugin using C# .net 4.8(vs 2017).  When I publish the app, the Microsoft.Windows.CommonLanguageRuntime is set to 4.0.30319.0 in the *.dll.manifiest file.  Is there a setting somewhere in visual studio to change the default value to 4.0.30319.18020?

Comment: What issue are you trying to solve...what happens if it's not that version?

Comment: On a test machine which resides on Azure the plugin works fine.  On the client machine the install is fine but then I get an error System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: SignatureDescription could not be created for the signature algorithm supplied.  I saw someone post an answer that I needed to update and resign the manifest file with that value using mage.  However I can't use mage because my code sign certificate is on a usb.  Mage only works with local .pfx files.

Comment: I also wanted to add that if I change the .net version to 4.0 on my application the plugin will work.  But all of the libraries I use do not work with 4.0 so I can't just downgrade my app.

Comment: Also the customer machine and my test machine both have .net 4.8 on them.   But they are slightly different versions.

Comment: I have a current VSTO Excel plugin which can't go above 4.7.2 due to pulling in a .Net Standard project. What happens if you drop to 4.7/4.6 instead?

Comment: I tried 4.7, 4.6 and 4.5 and I still got the same error.  Should I try the minor editions as well(ie 4.7.2, 4.7.1, 4.6.2, 4.6.1)?

Comment: See about resigning the cert. https://stackoverflow.com/q/10901035/285795

Comment: This was the article I mentioned earlier.  EV Certificates are now issued via USB sticks.  Which means you cannot load the private keys to your harddrive.  Mage only uses .pfx files.  So I am caught in a rock and a hard place because I cannot resign the app.

Comment: I have not found any command line parameters to force Mage to use a private key stored on a usb stick.